# Custom Application Encryption

Tags: c, encryption, tcp, public-key-encryption

I am currently looking to add encryption to a server application (programmed in C) that passes raw data, unencrypted data over TCP to clients (a large number of different applications programmed in many different languages).

What is the best way to do this? Public-key cryptography? If so, how would the process go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL suits my needs! A quick view at the documentation and tutorials pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to ask, you're probably not qualified to be doing cryptographic work. It is far to easy to make a subtle mistake in crypto processing that breaks your entire system's security, and unlike most other bugs, it is not at all obvious until someone else breaks your system.

Just use SSL (aka TLS). The folks that designed the SSL/TLS specs and libraries have already done all the hard work for you.

Comment: especially if you have "a large number of different applications programmed in many different languages". TLS is very widely supported.

Comment: Whether or not I'm qualified or not (which I'm not, admittedly) doesn't matter because the work needs to be done, and I'm the one to do it. So I'm therefore looking at the best way to get started.

Comment: Also, none of the other applications have support for encryption yet. The only thing I have control over is the server, so I'm looking for the best, most flexible way that other clients would be able to add this support for.

Comment: @Fran, what I mean by this is, it's fine to use a SSL library. But if you want to write a new SSL-like protocol from scratch, stop. Very few people have the kind of qualifications to do that and expect the result to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

SSL: secure socket layers, which initiates and transmits encrypted data.

TLS: transport layer security, which asks to starttls and the answer to that is a list of capabilities, then the transmission can continue using the best mutually accepted encryption.

Note: the capabilities may include cleartext.

I suggest reading upon how to extend  your existing protocol to support TLS, by looking at an example, say, the smtp starttls( rfc 2487 ).  your time invested will be rewarded.